# Is there a way to easily convert cfquery output to DataTable JSON format in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, google-visualization

I am trying to generate a chart using Google Charts API, but I can't seem to get the data in the required format.

`serializeJSON(data)` in coldfusion gives me the JSON data, but looks like that is not what the Charts API expects. Is there any component I can use to convert it to the required format?

### Query

```
<cfquery name="getAllUsers" datasource="cccac_swipe" result="UserDetailsResult">
Select login_mode,count(login_mode) as total from login_activity,ccac_registered_users where login_activity.student_id=ccac_registered_users.student_id GROUP BY login_mode
</cfquery>
```

### ColdFusion's JSON

```
{"COLUMNS":["LOGIN_MODE","TOTAL"],"DATA":[["manual",123],["swipe",20]]}
```

### Expected JSON

```
{ "cols": [ {"id":"","label":"SignIn Method","pattern":"","type":"string"}, {"id":"","label":"Count","pattern":"","type":"number"} ], "rows": [ {"c":[{"v":"manual","f":null},{"v":123,"f":null}]}, {"c":[{"v":"swipe","f":null},{"v":20,"f":null}]} ] }
```

Comment: have a look at this link http://www.mccran.co.uk/index.cfm/2010/4/29/JQuery-Datatables-plugin-example-using-a-server-side-data-request-coldfusion

Comment: @RachelGallen specifically looking for Google Charts API. I can already use the chart that is part of coldfusion.

Comment: It might help if you gave us an example of your query and the required format, we might be able to give you pointers on transforming it.

Comment: Generate a struct in coldfusion that mimics your expected structure, then serialize it. However, you still may have the issue of the keys being the wrong case depending on coldfusion version and application settings. The only way around that that i know of is to generate the json by hand or change the option in coldfusion that preserves case in var names.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the reply. I am generating the JSON by hand now, just wanted to check if there is a component/library that can do this automatically.

Comment: You're looking more for a transformation than a straight conversion. i.e. How does the column "LOGIN_MODE" get translated to "SignIn Method"? etc. You could write a custom function to do this, but it would be similar in terms of what you're doing now, just more structured.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is basically what you need.  Just plug in your query data.

```
<cfset chartsData = structNew()>
<cfset chartsData["cols"] = arrayNew(1)>

<!--- use a query loop to copy query data to this struct --->
<cfloop query="UserDetailsResult">
   <cfset chartsRow = structNew()>
   <cfset chartsRow["id"] = ""> 
   <cfset chartsRow["label"] = "SignIn Method">
   <cfset chartsRow["pattern"] = "">
   <cfset chartsRow["type"] = "string">

   <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow)>
</cfloop>

<cfset chartsDataJSON = serializeJSON(chartsData)>
```