# Formatting ColdFusion JSON from SQL query for Google Charts

Tags: json, charts, coldfusion, google-visualization

Full disclosure – I am very new to any kind of web coding, so TIA for your patience!

What I am trying to do is query for data and use it to build dynamic Google charts.  In Coldfusion I’ve queried SQL Server for data, then output as JSON (I validated this JSON on http://jsonlint.com/ and it says it is valid). 
If I try to directly use this JSON in a Google chart I get the error: “Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON string” because the format of the JSON is not what Google charts wants.

**Here is a snippet of the JSON that ColdFusion creates from the SQL query**:

```
{"COLUMNS":["DATE","TEMP_C"],"DATA":[["08\/09\/2016",27.04],["08\/09\/2016",26.98],["08\/09\/2016",27.02],      …etc
```

**Here’s the format that Google charts is expecting:**

```
{ 
"cols": [ 
    {"id":"","label":"SignIn Method","pattern":"","type":"string"},
    {"id":"","label":"Count","pattern":"","type":"number"} 
   ], 
"rows": [ 
    {"c":[{"v":"manual","f":null},{"v":123,"f":null}]}, 
    {"c":[{"v":"swipe","f":null},{"v":20,"f":null}]} 
   ] 
}
```

I’ve been trying to restructure the JSON to the format needed by Google charts and I can’t figure it out.  I’ve been trying to use the info in this question:
[Is there a way to easily convert cfquery output to DataTable JSON format in coldfusion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14466754/is-there-a-way-to-easily-convert-cfquery-output-to-datatable-json-format-in-cold)

So the section I have *sortof* working is this:

```
<cfset chartsData = structNew()>
<cfset chartsData["cols"] = arrayNew(1)>

<cfset chartsRow = structNew()>
   <cfset chartsRow["id"] = ""> 
   <cfset chartsRow["label"] = "Date">
   <cfset chartsRow["pattern"] = "">
   <cfset chartsRow["type"] = "date">

   <cfset chartsRow2["id"] = ""> 
   <cfset chartsRow2["label"] = "Temp_C">
   <cfset chartsRow2["pattern"] = "">
   <cfset chartsRow2["type"] = "number">  

   <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow)>
   <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow2)>

   <cfset chartsDataJSON = serializeJSON(chartsData)>

  <cfset chartsData2 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsData2["rows"] = arrayNew(1)>

  <!--- use a query loop to copy query data to this struct --->
   <cfloop query="qAEBdata">
   <cfset chartsRow3 = structNew()>
   <cfset chartsRow3["c"] = []>
   <cfset chartsRow3["v"] = "#Date#">
   <cfset chartsRow3["f"] = "null">
   <cfset chartsRow3["type"] = "date">

   <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData2["rows"], chartsRow3)>
   <cfset chartsDataJSON2 = serializeJSON(chartsData2)>
</cfloop>

   <cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON#,</cfoutput>
   <cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON2#</cfoutput>
```

Which results in this output:

```
{
"cols":[
{"pattern":"","label":"Date","id":"","type":"date"},
{"pattern":"","label":"Temp_C","id":"","type":"number"}
]
}, 
{    <!---note that google charts does not want this structure --->
"rows":[
{"f":"null","v":"08\/11\/2016","c":[],"type":"date"},
{"f":"null","v":"08\/11\/2016","c":[],"type":"date"},
{"f":"null","v":"08\/11\/2016","c":[],"type":"date"}   …etc
```

My questions/issues are:
(1) Why is it reordering the ‘id’, ‘label’, ‘pattern’, ‘type’ and the ‘c’,’v’,’f’,’type’? How do I correct this?
and
(2) Clearly I’m not structuring the format correctly, esp. for the rows, and I can’t figure out how to correct it. Can anyone please help nudge me in the right direction?

**UPDATE:**
I updated my code with the help of @WhiteHat and @Leigh, as such:

```
<cfquery name="qAEBdata" datasource="mydb">
SELECT convert(nvarchar, date, 101) AS Date, temp AS Temp_C
FROM mytable
WHERE threeletter = 'AEB'
and date > '8/11/2016' 
</cfquery> 

<cfset chartsData = structNew()>
   <cfset chartsData["cols"] = arrayNew(1)>
   <cfset chartsData["rows"] = arrayNew(1)>

   <cfset chartsRow = structNew()>
   <cfset chartsRow["id"] = ""> 
   <cfset chartsRow["label"] = "Date">
   <cfset chartsRow["pattern"] = "">
   <cfset chartsRow["type"] = "string">

   <cfset chartsRow2["id"] = ""> 
   <cfset chartsRow2["label"] = "Temp_C">
   <cfset chartsRow2["pattern"] = "">
   <cfset chartsRow2["type"] = "number">

   <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow)>
   <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow2)>

<cfloop query="qAEBdata">
  <cfset chartsRow3 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsRow3["c"] = []>
  <cfset chartsRow3Value0 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsRow3Value0["v"] = "#Date#">
  <cfset chartsRow3Value1 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsRow3Value1["v"] = "#Temp_C#">
  <cfset arrayAppend(chartsRow3["c"], chartsRow3Value0)>
  <cfset arrayAppend(chartsRow3["c"], chartsRow3Value1)>
  <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["rows"], chartsRow3)>
</cfloop>

<cfset chartsDataJSON = serializeJSON(chartsData)>
<cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON#,</cfoutput>
```

This puts the data into the correct JSON structure for Google charts EXCEPT my output has a a trailing comma at the very end (it's also putting rows before columns, but that doesn't seem to matter). Here's my output:

```
{"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"08\/12\/2016"},{"v":26.93}]},
{"c":[{"v":"08\/12\/2016"},{"v":26.94}]},
"cols":[
{"pattern":"","label":"Date","id":"","type":"string"},
{"pattern":"","label":"Temp_C","id":"","type":"number"}]},
```

I've tried adding each these methods (one at a time) after the 'serializeJSON' and they don't remove the comma. Increasing the "-1" to a higher number results in removing the brackets and eventually text from the data:

```
<cfset chartsDataJSON = reReplace(chartsDataJSON, ",$", "", "all")>
<cfset chartsDataJSON = chartsDataJSON.substring(0, len(chartsDataJSON)- 1)>
<cfset chartsDataJSON = left(chartsDataJSON, len(chartsDataJSON)-1)>
```

E.g. using this:

```
 <cfset chartsDataJSON = left(chartsDataJSON, len(chartsDataJSON)-2)>
```

Results in the end of the output looking like the following (note: result is a "]" bracket is missing from before the comma but comma is still there):

```
"cols":[{"pattern":"","label":"Date","id":"","type":"string"},{"pattern":"","label":"Temp_C","id":"","type":"number"},
```

**SECOND UPDATE**
I found where my stupid comma was and removed it, it was after where I'd output it, which makes sense why I couldn't remove it where I tried to:

```
<cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON#,</cfoutput>
```

I am trying to pull the JSON data into the Google chart and I'm getting "invalid JSON string":

```
<!---build chart--->  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var fusionObject = 'chartDataJSON';

    var chartsDataJSON = new google.visualization.DataTable(fusionObject);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(chartsDataJSON);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
  </script>
```

But if I paste in the JSON directly the chart draws just fine.

**FINAL UPDATE - JSON formatted correctly and chart draws!**
As Leigh pointed out, I needed to call the variable correctly for ColdFusion (a duh moment for me). Corrected code below:

```
 <!---build chart--->  
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script>
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var fusionObject = ('<cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON#</cfoutput>');

    var chartsDataJSON = new google.visualization.DataTable(fusionObject);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(chartsDataJSON);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: *Why is it reordering* Unlike arrays, structures have no guaranteed order. However, I doubt google cares about the order. Most likely the problem is that the overall data structures are still different. ie "cols" and "rows" should be keys inside *one* structure, not two separate structures.  I have only skimmed briefly, but one thing that stands out is multiple calls to serializeJSON(). You should only call it once.  Build the proper structures/arrays first, then call serializeJSON at the end.

Comment: *I’ve been trying to use the info in this question* Looks like that code is only a starting point. It would not produce the exact format you posted above.  Try starting with something like this: http://trycf.com/gist/e39995c59af5c2e3e37f648dc94faa73/acf?theme=monokai

Comment: Side note, while there is nothing technically wrong with using `arrayNew` and `structNew()`, newer versions of CF support a shorthand format for both, that is a bit more readable IMO. `{}` - [Shorthand for structNew()](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/729.cfm) and `[]` - shorthand for ArrayNew(1). To preserve the case of structure keys (which is important to javascript), enclose key names in quotes: ie `<cfset myStruct = { "key": "some value", "otherKey": 123 }>`

Comment: BTW, since you mentioned being new to CF, you might want to throw your working code up on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for suggestions on best practices and possible improvements. Be sure to include your CF version `<cfdump var="#server#">`.

Comment: Thanks @Leigh! I'll check it out, you're always so generous with your help. I'm new to any and all coding (5mon) so it's very much appreciated.

Comment: Aw, thanks :) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"rows"` needs to be added to the same object as `"cols"`

each `"c"` also needed some changes

using the following snippet...

```
<!--- simulate data query --->
<cfset qAEBdata = queryNew("")>
<cfset queryAddColumn(qAEBdata, "Date", "varchar", ["08/09/2016","08/10/2016","08/11/2016"])>
<cfset queryAddColumn(qAEBdata, "Temp_C", "decimal", [27.04,26.98,27.02])>

<cfset chartsData = structNew()>
<cfset chartsData["cols"] = arrayNew(1)>
<cfset chartsData["rows"] = arrayNew(1)>

<cfset chartsRow = structNew()>
<cfset chartsRow["id"] = "">
<cfset chartsRow["label"] = "Date">
<cfset chartsRow["pattern"] = "">
<cfset chartsRow["type"] = "string">

<cfset chartsRow2["id"] = "">
<cfset chartsRow2["label"] = "Temp_C">
<cfset chartsRow2["pattern"] = "">
<cfset chartsRow2["type"] = "number">

<cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow)>
<cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["cols"], chartsRow2)>

<cfloop query="qAEBdata">
  <cfset chartsRow3 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsRow3["c"] = []>
  <cfset chartsRow3Value0 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsRow3Value0["v"] = "#Date#">
  <cfset chartsRow3Value1 = structNew()>
  <cfset chartsRow3Value1["v"] = "#Temp_C#">
  <cfset arrayAppend(chartsRow3["c"], chartsRow3Value0)>
  <cfset arrayAppend(chartsRow3["c"], chartsRow3Value1)>
  <cfset arrayAppend(chartsData["rows"], chartsRow3)>
</cfloop>

<cfset chartsDataJSON = serializeJSON(chartsData)>
<cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON#</cfoutput>
```

at the [try cold fusion gist runner](http://trycf.com/gist/9846f4962ba4cc99f69c1ede2cc9bdec/acf2016?theme=monokai) provided by @Leigh

i was able to create the following JSON

```
{
  "cols": [{
    "pattern": "",
    "label": "Date",
    "id": "",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "pattern": "",
    "label": "Temp_C",
    "id": "",
    "type": "number"
  }],
  "rows": [{
    "c": [{
      "v": "08/09/2016"
    }, {
      "v": 27.04
    }]
  }, {
    "c": [{
      "v": "08/10/2016"
    }, {
      "v": 26.98
    }]
  }, {
    "c": [{
      "v": "08/11/2016"
    }, {
      "v": 27.02
    }]
  }]
}
```

which produces the following chart...
(run following snippet)

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var fusionObject = {"cols":[{"pattern":"","label":"Date","id":"","type":"string"},{"pattern":"","label":"Temp_C","id":"","type":"number"}],"rows":[{"c":[{"v":"08/09/2016"},{"v":27.04}]},{"c":[{"v":"08/10/2016"},{"v":26.98}]},{"c":[{"v":"08/11/2016"},{"v":27.02}]}]};

    var chartsDataJSON = new google.visualization.DataTable(fusionObject);

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(chartsDataJSON);
  },
  packages: ['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

BUT, had to change the first column to `type: 'string'`
not sure how to get an actual date to JSON from ColdFusion

Comment: True, but take a look at the format of the desired string again. The generated structure of the query data still looks a little off.

Comment: Gotcha. If you are curious, use trycf.com. Here is a starter gist you can run and/or modify  :-) http://trycf.com/gist/9846f4962ba4cc99f69c1ede2cc9bdec/acf2016?theme=monokai  .

Comment: thanks to @Leigh for the scratch pad link -- i think i was able to come up with the ColdFusion code to get the chart to work -- hope this helps...

Comment: thanks, guys, I'll try these and let you know. I really appreciate the help!

Comment: This is really great, the only issue is that it's adding a comma to the end, so if I try to pull the JSON directly into the Google chart code I still get the "invalid JSON string" error.  But if I copy and paste the JSON output in and remove the comma the chart draws just fine. 
Any idea how to remove the comma? 
{"rows":[
{"c":[{"v":"08\/12\/2016"},{"v":26.93}]},
{"c":[{"v":"08\/12\/2016"},{"v":26.94}]},
"cols":[
{"pattern":"","label":"Date","id":"","type":"string"},
{"pattern":"","label":"Temp_C","id":"","type":"number"}]},

Comment: Hmm, that's not working. I reformatted your idea so that it worked for coldfusion: 
    <cfset chartsDataJSON = chartsDataJSON.substring(0, len(chartsDataJSON)- 1)>   
but it's not removing the comma. If I test it by increasing the value to remove (eg. -2) it keeps the comma but will remove the last ] bracket.  I also tried this: 
    <cfset chartsDataJSON = left(chartsDataJSON, len(chartsDataJSON)-1)>  
which has the same effect. Comma stays, but increasing the subtraction value removes more and more of the brackets/JSON data.

Comment: @Becalecca - Are you sure you are using the exact code above to generate the JSON string? Because if you run it, you can see the example does not add any trailing commas. Sounds like it is being added somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @Leigh - I added an update to my question. Besides an actual query I can't see any code differences, most of it I pasted in and just checked over. Maybe I'm missing something? I don't know where the comma is coming from or why I can't remove it! Thank you both for your help!

Comment: omg, I just found it.  I had <cfoutput>#chartsDataJSON#,</cfoutput>

Comment: Well I fixed the comma mistake, but I can't get the chart to accept the data. I must be pulling it in wrong. If I copy and paste the formatted JSON in it works but if I call it like: 
    `var fusionObject = ('chartsDataJSON');`
I get the "invalid JSON string" error.

Comment: if I removed the apostrophes I get no errors in the console, but where the chart should show up I get a red box with `"Table has no columns.×"`

Comment: @Becalecca - Without pound signs and `<cfoutput>`, the CF variable is never evaluated. So the code is actually passing in the literal string "chartsDataJSON", not the *value* of the variable by that name.

Comment: Duh! Leigh, you're a savior! I tried pound signs but didn't even think about '<cfoutput>', how dense. THANK YOU! Solved, huge thanks to @WhiteHat and Leigh!